# Python code quality aspects list comprehension versus numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I am doing an online course on machine learning. To get better predictions we should implement a python function to remove 10% of the outlier data. I have solved the quest - yet I have found two different solutions and I would like to hear your comments according code quality.

```
def outlierCleaner(predictions, ages, net_worths):
"""
    Clean away the 10% of points that have the largest
    residual errors (difference between the prediction
    and the actual net worth).

    Return a list of tuples named cleaned_data where
    each tuple is of the form (age, net_worth, error).
"""

# first approach just using list comprehension
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
cleaned_data = []
cleaned_data = [(age, net_worth, (prediction-net_worth)**2)\
    for age, net_worth, prediction \
    in zip(ages, net_worths, predictions)]
last_index = int(len(cleaned_data)*0.9-1)
cleaned_data = sorted(cleaned_data, key = lambda t: t[2])
cleaned_data = cleaned_data[0:last_index]
stop = timeit.default_timer()
runtime1 = stop - start

# second approach. converting lists to numpy arrays, doing the math and
# converting back to a list of tuples.
start = timeit.default_timer()
import numpy as np
predictions_array = np.reshape(np.array(predictions), (len(predictions), 1))
ages_array = np.reshape(np.array(ages), (len(ages), 1))
net_worths_array = np.reshape(np.array(net_worths), (len(net_worths), 1))
cleaned_data = np.concatenate((ages_array, net_worths_array, (predictions_array-net_worths_array)**2), axis=1)
cleaned_data = cleaned_data[cleaned_data[:,2].argsort()]
cleaned_data = cleaned_data[:last_index+1, :]
#print "cleaned_data size:", cleaned_data.size, "dimens: ", cleaned_data.shape
cleaned_data = [tuple(row) for row in cleaned_data]
#print "length of cleaned_data:", len(cleaned_data)
runtime2 = stop - start
#print "runtime with lists: ", runtime1
#print "runtime with np.arrays: ", runtime2
#
# The second approach with numpy arrays seems to work a bit faster.
return cleaned_data
```

The second approach with the help of numpy arrays seems to run faster (0.000577926635742 vs. 0.0) on my machine.

Beside the fact of runtime which version do you think is more appropriate?

Comment: go with numpy its more efficient

Comment: If data is already in `np.array` form, try to use the compiled array methods as much as possible.  If the data is in list form, list comprehension is often faster.  There is a substantial overhead in creating an array from lists.  This has been discussed in many SO questions.